# How many columns can phpmyadmin can handle?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using `phpmyadmin` and there are 194 columns in 1 table and I'm still planning to add more `columns`. Is that okay? or will I encounter error in the future?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL itself has a [number of limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html), which you may already be aware of. Aside from that, phpMyAdmin has no theoretical limit, although you may hit PHP resource limits that cause the practical limit to be less than that.

PHP enforces various resource limits, including execution time and memory consumtion — these are dependent on your configuration and may affect your usage if you have a large number of columns, but it's difficult to predict whether this will affect your situation. If you have administrative access to the server, you can increase the limits if you encounter trouble.

Aside from that, I question your database design and wonder whether there might be a better way to store your data.

Comment: such a table design might involve denormalization, wich is used to improve performance